# How can I get the length of a protein chain from a PDB file with Biopython?

Tags: biopython

I have tried it this way first:

```
for model in structure:
    for residue in model.get_residues():
        if PDB.is_aa(residue):
            x += 1
```

and then that way:

```
len(structure[0][chain])
```

But none of them seem to work...

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work and give you the correct results.

```
from Bio import PDB
parser = PDB.PDBParser()

pdb1 ='./1bfg.pdb' 
structure = parser.get_structure("1bfg", pdb1) 
model = structure[0]
res_no = 0
non_resi = 0

for model in structure:
    for chain in model:
        for r in chain.get_residues():
            if r.id[0] == ' ':
                res_no +=1
            else:
                non_resi +=1

print ("Residues:  %i" % (res_no))
print ("Other:     %i" % (non_resi))
res_no2 = 0
non_resi2 = 0
for model in structure:
    for residue in model.get_residues():
        if PDB.is_aa(residue):
            res_no2 += 1

        else:
            non_resi2 += 1

print ("Residues2: %i" % (res_no2))
print ("Other2:    %i" % (non_resi2))
```

Output:

```
Residues:  126
Other:     99
Residues2: 126
Other2:    99
```

Your statement

```
print (len(structure[0]['A']))
```

gives you the sum (225) of all residues, in this case all amino acids and water atoms.

The numbers seem to be correct when compared to manual inspection using PyMol.

What is the specific error message you are getting or the output you are expecting? Any specific PDB file?

---

Since the PDB file is mostly used to store the coordinates of the resolved atoms, it is not always possible to get the full structure. Another approach would be use to the `cif` files.

```
from Bio import PDB
parser = PDB.PDBParser()

pdb1 ='./1bfg.cif'

m = PDB.MMCIF2Dict.MMCIF2Dict(pdb1)

if '_entity_poly.pdbx_seq_one_letter_code' in m.keys():
    print ('Full structure:')
    full_structure = (m['_entity_poly.pdbx_seq_one_letter_code'])
    print (full_structure)
    print (len(full_structure))
```

Output:

> Full structure:
>   PALPEDGGSGAFPPGHFKDPKRLYCKNGGFFLRIHPDGRVDGVREKSDPHIKLQLQAEERGVVSIKGVSANRYLAMKEDGRLLASKSVTDECFFFERLESNNYNTYRSRKYTSWYVALKRTGQYKLGSKTGPGQKAILFLPMSAKS
>   146

---

For multiple chains:

```
from Bio import PDB
parser = PDB.PDBParser()

pdb1 ='./4hlu.cif'

m = PDB.MMCIF2Dict.MMCIF2Dict(pdb1)

if '_entity_poly.pdbx_seq_one_letter_code' in m.keys():
    full_structure = m['_entity_poly.pdbx_seq_one_letter_code']
    chains = m['_entity_poly.pdbx_strand_id']
    for c in chains:
        print('Chain %s' % (c))
        print('Sequence: %s' % (full_structure[chains.index(c)]))
```

Comment: I dont get an error but the same numbers like you. But even here in your case the output is 126 but on the pdb-site it shows for 1bfg the length of 146 for chain A. And this is the result im looking for.

Comment: I think I found the solution:

Comment: for model in structure[0][chain]:
        if PDB.is_aa(model):
            chain_len += 1

Comment: And how can I get the length of a specific chain from the cif files?

Comment: @hobo: see updated answer. Well, I guess we both like challenges :)

Comment: I think I can work with that. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I have a question regarding the '_entity_poly.pdbx_seq_one_letter_code'. Does it output the full sequence of the protein, even if some missing residues have not been solved in the 3D structure? Some proteins may have engineered mutations. Within this keyword '_entity_poly.pdbx_seq_one_letter_code' do we get the sequence of the protein as it is from the 3D solved structure or the canonical one (as it is in UniProtKB for example?)

Answer (score 0):

It's just:

```
from Bio.PDB import PDBParser
from Bio import PDB                                                       


pdb = PDBParser().get_structure("1bfg", "1bfg.pdb")

for chain in pdb.get_chains():
    print(len([_ for _ in chain.get_residues() if PDB.is_aa(_)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I appreciated [Peters'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38030921/14379258) answer, but I also realized the `res.id[0] == " "` is more robust (i.e. HIE). PDB.is_aa() cannot detect HIE is an amino acid while HIE is ε-nitrogen protonated histidine. So I recommend:

```
from Bio import PDB
parser = PDB.PDBParser()

pdb1 ='./1bfg.pdb' 
structure = parser.get_structure("1bfg", pdb) 
model = structure[0]
res_no = 0
non_resi = 0

for model in structure:
    for chain in model:
        for r in chain.get_residues():
            if r.id[0] == ' ':
                res_no +=1
            else:
                non_resi +=1

print ("Residues:  %i" % (res_no))
print ("Other:     %i" % (non_resi))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would actually want to do something like

```
m = Bio.PDB.MMCIF2Dict.MMCIF2Dict(pdb_cif_file)
if '_entity_poly.pdbx_seq_one_letter_code' in m.keys():
    full_structure = m['_entity_poly.pdbx_seq_one_letter_code']
    chains = m['_entity_poly.pdbx_strand_id']
    for c in chains:
        for ci in c.split(','):
            print('Chain %s' % (ci))
            print('Sequence: %s' % (full_structure[chains.index(c)]))
```